# Упоминание ника редактора сообщения в комментариях

Tags: предложение, комментарии

Как известно, при комментировании вопроса или ответа есть возможность быстрого выбора ника из списка уже комментировавших (ввести @ и первую букву ника).

Хотелось бы чтобы в этот список попадали также и ники редакторов комментируемого вопроса или ответа.

Т.к. иногда есть желание обратиться именно к редактору в комментарии. В этом случае приходится указывать ник путем полного ввода, что не всегда удобно, особенно когда ник длинный и содержит, например, пробелы. При этом нет 100% уверенности, что уведомление дойдёт до адресата, например, из-за опечатки или неправильного формата. Когда же ник выбирается из списка, значит движок уже определил участника и уведомление им будет получено.

Comment: копирование спешит на помощь :-)

Answer (score 4):

Это стандартная механика. Идеологически, комментарии предназначены для запроса уточнения. Система не должна поощрять любое использование комментариев, тем более не по теме сообщения – обсуждение ошибок редактирования должно быть вынесено на Мету или в чат.

Comment: тогда скорее - так задумано :-) и не будет реализовано :-)

Comment: Вот я и хотел как раз у Вас уточнить по меткам статус-завершено, добавленным в вопрос :) После чего родилась такая идея. А раз уж поощрений быть не должно, то почему бы и имеющийся функционал не подсократить?

Comment: @alexolut Пожалуйста, поясните, что именно стоит сократить?

Comment: Например, убрать возможность автоподстановки ников при комментировании вовсе. Меньше удобств - меньше вероятность использования. Просто пока мне не понятно, почему обращение к редактору сообщения в комментариях Вы считаете не относящимся к теме сообщения.

Comment: Бывает, что нужно написать редактору. Например "Пожалуйста, больше не делайте таких правок". )